# Turn ON and OFF WIFI on my router using e.g. curl

Tags: javascript, html, bash, curl

**The problem**

During night hours, I want to turn off WIFI only WLR-9500 router. I want to accomplish this using a bash script from my synology NAS. Unfortunately I cannot install OpenWRT on my router, nor is there a timing table in there to turn wifi ON and OFF during predetermined hours.

**What did I try so far**

I have been fiddling around quite a lot with the curl command, but to to no avail yet.
I managed to login into the router, and *get* the page that manages the radio ON/OFF, and this page/frame (using a web browser allows to turn of radio)

This is what the pageframe looks like:
[image]

Which is actually a subframe of this page:
[image]

The page frame (html) source from the router looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="incjs.htm"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
IncJs({init:INC_ADV_PAGE}); 
</script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sysOPMode=0;
    var enableRadio="";

function saveChanges()
{
    return true;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("/cgi-bin/wlan.cgi",{info:wlan_info.WEB_WLAN_BASIC,radio_idx:r_idx.R_24G},function (data){
    enableRadio = data.WLANINFO.basicINFO[0].radio_enable;
    if (data.WLANINFO.basicINFO[0].radio_enable==1)
    getById("radioEnable").checked=true;
    else
    getById("radioDisable").checked=true;
    });
})

</script>
</head>
<body style="background-image:none;background-color:transparent;">
<br><br>
<blockquote>
<p><script type="text/javascript">dw(showText(80))</script></p>
<form name="wirelessseting" method="post" action="submit.cgi">
<input type="hidden" name="submitpg" value="wlmain.html">
<br>
<table width="900px" border="0" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:bold;"><script type="text/javascript">dw(showText(81))</script>&nbsp;:&nbsp;
<input type="radio" id="radioEnable" name="radioEnable" value="1" ><script type="text/javascript">dw(showText(76) + '&nbsp;')</script>
<input type="radio" id="radioDisable" name="radioEnable" value="0"><script type="text/javascript">dw(showText(88))</script>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<table  width="100%" cellspacing="1">
<tbody><tr><td>
<div align="right">
<script type="text/javascript">dw('<input type="submit" value="'+showText(46)+'" onClick="return saveChanges()"  width="105">')</script>
</script>
</div>
</td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>            
</form>
</blockquote>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried the many cariations on the curl command, but without success. Once I get this curl command (or sequence of curl commands?) right, I am pretty sure I will manage to create my bash script that I will put in here as well.

I used the curl statement below to test if I get access to the page, and this completes successfully. Though no cjar file is generated, so I guess no cookies are produced.

```
 curl --anyauth --cookie-jar cjar -u admin:xxxpassxxx -g http://192.168.178.1/wlmain.html
```

Next I try to disable the radio like this:

```
 curl --anyauth -u admin:xxxpassxxx --cookie-jar cjar -F "radioEnable=0" http://192.168.178.1/wlmain.html
```

(And many variations on that command line)

**The question**

How can I do this from a command line using e.g. curl?

Comment: You can use wireshark to examine the requests made to enable the wifi. The request is most likely submitted to `submit.cgi` but it's unclear if `radioEnable=1` is all the parameter that's needed. Better be sure.

Comment: Ah good idea... let's see whats going down :)

Comment: Or the [copy as curl](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/copyas) feature in your favorite browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @konsolebox suggested: the solution was using [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to find out what was actually posted by the page:

```
submitpg=wlmain.html&radioEnable=0
```

The filter I used in wireshark was the following:

```
ip.addr eq 192.168.178.1 and ip.addr eq 192.168.178.100
```

And found out what was was posted to `http:\\192.168.178.1\submit.cgi` from my desktop with ap address `192.168.178.100`

So... the entire curl command had to look like this, having 1 parameter for the `radioEnable` parameter and one for the `submitpg`

```
 curl --anyauth -u admin:xxxPASSxxx -d "radioEnable=1&submitpg=wlmain.html" http://192.168.178.1/submit.cgi
```

Tested this on command line from my windows desktop, and it works just fine. Next step to do the same for my Access Point as well, but I'm pretty sure I can manage that from here.

Once in place and working, I will drop the final bash script here as well.

And as promised the script to turn the WIFI ON or OFF, which is called by the automated task table of my Synology NAS. The `sleep` is required because the router is "busy" during the restart of the radio module and wont accept any other commands.

*RouterWifiOnOff*

```
#turn off/on WIFI on AC2600/WLR9500 router

# 2.4GHz network
curl --anyauth -u admin:xxxPASSxxx -d "radioEnable=$1&submitpg=wlmain.html" http://192.168.178.1/submit.cgi

# allow the router to process this
sleep 15 

# 5.0 GHz Wifi network
curl --anyauth -u admin:xxxPASSxxx -d "radioEnable=$1&submitpg=wlmain2.html" http://192.168.178.1/submit.cgi

# set RE200/OpenWRT access point wifi UP or DOWN
if [ $1 -eq 0 ] 
then
  ssh root@192.168.178.2 'wifi down'
else 
  ssh root@192.168.178.2 'wifi up'
fi
```

The parameter provided to the script (`0` or `1`) determines whether the wifi will be enabled/disabled. The call in the task table looks like this:

```
 bash /volume1/homes/admin/WifiOnOffScripts/RouterWIFI_OnOff 0
```

I have later added the statement to show how to drive wifi on/off for my OpenWRT access point. This involves setting up a RSA key pair before you can actually run it (you cannot provide a password to SSH), but how this goes is beyond the topic.